# CommandText Issue

Tags: sql, excel, vba

When I try to execute this code in my excel VBA script, I get an error saying "invalid Procedure call or argument". Everything looks good to me, so where am I going wrong? Below is the code, thanks!

```
, Destination:=Range("$A$3")).QueryTable
   .CommandText = Array( _
"Select C.SafetyStockQty as SftyStock, C.QtyOnHand as QOH01, G.QtyOnHand as QOHOF,D.QtyOnHand as QOHRDS,E.QtyOnHand as QOHRW ,H.QtyOnHand as QOH02 ,I.QtyOnHand as QOHP1 ,J.QtyOnHand as QOHPDS , F.GrossReqRule as GRR , F.PartCategory as Category ,F.LeadTime " & _
"From CompanyR.dbo.InvWarehouse C " _
, _
"left join CompanyR.dbo.InvWarehouse D on C.StockCode = D.StockCode and D.Warehouse = 'DS' " & _
"left join CompanyR.dbo.InvWarehouse E on C.StockCode = E.StockCode and E.Warehouse = 'RW' " _
, _
"left join CompanyR.dbo.InvWarehouse G on C.StockCode = G.StockCode and G.Warehouse = 'OF' " _
, _
"left join CompanyR.dbo.InvWarehouse H on C.StockCode = H.StockCode and H.Warehouse = '02' " _
, _
"left join CompanyP.dbo.InvWarehouse I on C.StockCode = I.StockCode and I.Warehouse = '01' " _
, _
"left join CompanyP.dbo.InvWarehouse J on C.StockCode = J.StockCode and J.Warehouse = 'DS' " _
, _
"left Join CompanyR.dbo.InvMaster F on C.StockCode = F.StockCode " & _
"where C.StockCode = '" & StckCd & "' And C.Warehouse = '01' " _
)
```

Comment: You might need to share a bit more: what is your .CommandType, for example. Is your SQL correct (did you run it directly against the database)?

Comment: So I’ve got two databases in here. CompanyR and CompanyP - I did run it directly against the database as I set up an ODBC connection the line before